# Spring Security Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure anyRequest after itself

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I get this error while trying to start the spring boot application and I can't seem to figure out why. Any help is highly appreciated.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure anyRequest after itself

Fails at super.configure(http) method.
This is my 'SpringSecurityConfig.java' class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailService customUserDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public JWTAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JWTAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

            http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        super.configure(http);
    }




    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {

        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

Full stack trace

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure anyRequest after itself
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:645) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:475) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at lk.apiit.eirlss.bnco_vehicle_rental_backend.BncoVehicleRentalBackendApplication.main(BncoVehicleRentalBackendApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure anyRequest after itself
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       ... 26 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure anyRequest after itself
>       at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.anyRequest(AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.java:74) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:355) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at lk.apiit.eirlss.bnco_vehicle_rental_backend.Auth.Config.SpringSecurityConfig.configure(SpringSecurityConfig.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
>       at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:231) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:322) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:92) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at lk.apiit.eirlss.bnco_vehicle_rental_backend.Auth.Config.SpringSecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$10db399e.init() ~[classes/:na]
>       at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:370) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:324) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       ... 27 common frames omitted

Comment: IllegalStateException is just a surface exception. There is something else going wrong underneath. Can you paste the complete stack trace- maybe there is ClassCadtException below on the stack trace. Also look to increase log level for .org.speingframework.security to DEBUG level to get more info

Comment: @SriniM, I added the full stack trace after u mentioned it in your comment. It would be really great if I can get a fix for this. Your help is appreciated:)

Comment: One suggestion I can give is start commenting out line by line in the configure() method to see if any of the line is causing this error.

Comment: I had a similar issue since one of the latest `spring-boot` updates. Was getting the same exception, In my case I had two `anyRequest` calls in my initialization code, which seems to lead to an exception now as there is an assertion in the source of `anyRequest`. In your case it could be something similar although you don't do that exactly.

Comment: In new version of spring-security-config, I faced this issue. Couldn't solve it, I had to degrade the version of it. This may help : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/7970

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You should not call `super.configure(http)` since you want to use a custom security configuration.

The error is caused because the parent `configure(http)` method is already calling `.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()` and as the error message mentions

> Can't configure anyRequest after itself

Comment: Thank you. @Eleftheria Stein-Kousathana, my application works after commenting super.configure(http) out. So it's either one.

Comment: In my case a legacy application I was upgrading had a line `.anyRequest().authenticated()` and another one `.anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic()` but the reason was exactly the same. I removed the first one and that got me going.  Thanks for documenting this!