# Spring Security Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure anyRequest after itself [SpringBoot update 2.1.4 -> 2.3.11]

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am updating the my existing springboot project from 2.1.4 -> 2.3.11

The exiting code of class which extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is as below

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
             http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and().cors().disable()
            .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .and().csrf().disable()
            .addFilterBefore(new GenericFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(new SomeTokenFilter(tokensService), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

This is a existing code which  is working before updating. After I update I am getting below logs as application starts:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure anyRequest after itself
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76) ~[spring-core-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.anyRequest(AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.java:74) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at com.moglix.wms.config.SecurityConfig.configure(SecurityConfig.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:231) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:322) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:94) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at com.moglix.wms.config.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2778b12e.init(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:370) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:324) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.9.RELEASE.jar:5.3.9.RELEASE
```

Comment: As the error message says you cannot configure `anyRequest` when you have already configured `anyRequest`. If you require users to be fully authenticated remove the line `authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()`. Otherwise remove the line `authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59004025/spring-security-error-java-lang-illegalstateexception-cant-configure-anyreque/59066855

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have 2 times `anyRequest()` in your configuration. This is [no longer allowed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6359) starting with Spring Security 5.2.